# Is there a special value to omit fields from jq output?

Tags: json, key, jq

I can easily conditionally set a field to `null`:

```sh
echo '{"id": 1, "more": "fields"}' \
  | jq '{newId: (if .id == 1 then null else .id end), newMore: .more}'
```

yields

```
{
  "newId": null,
  "newMore": "fields"
}
```

But how can I conditionally delete it? I'm looking for something like:

```sh
echo '{"id": 1, "more": "fields"}' \
  | jq '{
          newId: (if .id == 1 then <special-value> else .id end), 
          newMore: .more
       }'
```

to yield

```
{
  "newMore": "fields"
}
```

Does such a `<special-value>` exist? If not, what are other viable solutions? They should ideally also be usable for large objects with many additional and nested fields.

Comment: *Does such a <special-value> exist?* No, object construction operator (`{}`) does not allow for that.

Comment: @adius - See the answer using `empty` in conjunction with `// {}`

Answer (score 1):

In that case you might want to create your object inside the `if` statement:

```
echo '{"id": 1}' | jq 'if .id == 1 then {} else {newId: .id} end'
```

Comment: For small objects certainly a feasible solution, for bigger ones not so much.

Comment: @adius - The question you asked does not mention any large objects.  If the real question you have concerns large objects, then please elaborate in the main body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could adopt the convention that, if a key's value is `null` (or `nan`), the key can be deleted.  To delete all the null-valued keys, you can use `map_values(select(. != null))` (or `map_values(select(isnan|not))`).

Thus, using your example, we find:

```
$ echo '{"id": 1}' | jq '{newId: (if .id == 1 then null else .id end)} | map_values( select(. != null))'
{}
```

and:

```
$ echo '{"id": 1}' | jq '{newId: (if .id == 1 then nan else .id end)} | map_values( select(isnan|not))'
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jq 1.5 or later, you can use `empty` as the "special value" as follows:

```
echo '{"id": 1}' | jq '. as $in 
  | reduce "newId" as $k (.; .[$k] = if .id == 1 then empty else .id end)'
```

The point is that you can handle indefinitely many keys this way; for example, if you have a list, $l, of key names to be added conditionally, you would write: `reduce $l[] as $k ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `empty` as the special value along with `// {}`:

```
$ echo '{"id": 1}' | jq '{newId: (if .id == 1 then empty else .id end) } // {} '
{}
```

This technique can also be used add a field conditionally, e.g.

```
$ echo '{"id": 1}' | jq '. += ({newId: (if .id == 1 then empty else .id end) } // {})'
{
  "id": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now went with a solution where I conditionally add the fields in the end. Looks a little overkill for such a small object, but if you're dealing with bigger objects with a lot of additional fields, it's a very clean way.

```sh
echo '{"id": 1, "more": "fields"}' \
| jq '.id as $id
       | {newMore: .more} 
       | if $id == 1 then . else . + {newId: $id} end
     '
```